# how to set intent action using value stored in string

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to add a functionality in my App, where a user can make buttons to launch apps on the device. Now, to set this up the user will enter the Intent Action they want to invoke. If user enters "ACTION_MAIN" as a string value, is it possible to process it as Intent.ACTION_MAIN in java ?

I know using a map can be one solution but maintaining an exhaustive list of all available intents can be cumbersome. Is their any other solution to this ? Can string value reference a variable ?

Comment: Can you give an example of Java code how you want to process `Intent.ACTION_MAIN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say the user defined action as a string value is stored in `userInput`:

```
String userInput = "ACTION_MAIN";
```

You can get the corresponding value of `Intent.<ACTION_SOMETHING>` using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) as follows:

```
try {
    String action = (String) Intent.class.getDeclaredField(userInput).get(String.class);
    // use the action value here..
} catch (Exception e) {
    // no such action possible, maybe mistyped the action name
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Example**:

```
String action = (String) Intent.class.getDeclaredField("ACTION_MAIN").get(String.class);
```

returns:

```
"android.intent.action.MAIN"
```